# Free tool to import data from SQL Server to SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2?

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-ce

I found that page: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

There are a lot of tools but it is not clear which one will do the job right, so any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export2SqlCe.exe will "do the job right" (I am the developer, so please let me know if that is not the case) - Usage guide here:
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html